# ASP .net SharePoint UI

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, web, sharepoint-2013

Ok this is my first time using a SharePoint for hosting a web page. I have some test pages that i want to place on a Sharepoint. I have three pages that i need to host. My Default.aspx, Default.aspx.cs, and the Web Config file. I am starting off simple just to show that I can upload. Everything i found was someone asking about authentication or some other issue. My guess would be to paste the Default.aspx page into the SitePages folder then place the other two files into the Site Assets Folder but I am not sure and do not want to go around wildly placing files places and messing up the site up all togther. Also if i do have to place the files in two seperate locations do i need to add to my code to point to the web config file and or the Default.aspx.cs file.

When I copied the contents of Default.aspx into SharePoint Designer and loaded the page this is the only thing displayed in the window

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
```

Thanks in Advance for helping a newbie to web

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs"  Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<p>
    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" Enabled="true" />
    <asp:Button ID="UploadButton" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="UploadButton_Click" />
    <asp:Label ID="LabelTest" runat="server" /> 
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
 {
     protected void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

  {
        if(FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("ProcessingFolder") + @"/" + FileUpload1.FileName);
        Saved = true;
    }
}
 }
```

Web Config:

Answer (score 0):

If you are not familiar with SharePoint. You can always use back your ASP.Net knowledge and apply to it...
You can use Visual Web Part. 
As per the following [link](http://www.sharepoint-journey.com/visual-webpart-in-sharepoint-2013.html)

You can also use layouts folder which locate at `c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS` 
Inside the layouts folder you may create a folder and put all your code inside.

To access the page with folder `http://yourSharePoint/_layouts/15/foldername/yourpage.aspx`

Without folder `http://yourSharePoint/_layouts/15/yourpage.aspx`

To access the web config you need to have the following code

```
using System.Configuration;
```

Then access your appsetting in web.config

```
string a = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PATH"];
```

In your web.config

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="PATH" value="C:\\Test\\UploadedFolder"/>
</appSettings>
```